# Android fragment backstack behaving weird

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

My application currently has a single activity and a bunch of fragments.  I want when the user presses the back button on their phone that they move backwards through the UI instead of exiting the application.

I override onBackPressed() in my main activity...

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
        fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
    } else if(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("Seizure Tracker").isVisible()) {
        if (backButtonPressed + 3000 > System.currentTimeMillis())
            super.onBackPressed();
        else {
            backButtonPressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Press back again to exit.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

This seems to work fine except for one transition.  Basically I move from fragment A -> B -> C press back and fragment A shows up.  Press back again and instead of the message "Press back again to exit" nothing happens.  Press back again and the message shows up.

If I go

```
 A -> B -> C back (now at A) -> B -> C back
```

I end up at B.  If I press back again I stay at B.  Press back again and I get to A.  Press back again and the message "Press back again to exit" shows up.

If I go

```
A -> B -> C -> D back (now at C) back
```

I end up at A in the same state as if I went A -> B -> C back.  So basically D back to C works fine as does every other back transition.

In my Main activity I have a listener for when the back state changes so I can update the actionBar

```
getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
            new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
                public void onBackStackChanged() {
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    System.out.println("changed: "+fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount());
                    for(int i = 0; i < fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount(); i++)
                        System.out.println("name: "+fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(i).getName());

                    // Update your UI here.
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .findFragmentById(R.id.container).getTag());
                }
            });
```

This updates the actionBar as if the back transitions were working as intended.  I also added the print lines and they are telling me that the back transitions are working as intended and I can see nothing weird from printing:

```
for(int i = 0; i < fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount(); i++)
     System.out.println("name:"+fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(i).getName());
```

I am using a navigationDrawer maybe that has some effect on this...

```
switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                System.out.println(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount());
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container, new SeizureTrackerFragment(), "Seizure Tracker")
                        .commit();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container, new SetupFragment(), "Setup")
                        .commit();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container, new AboutFragment(), "About")
                        .commit();
                break;
        }
```

If I start at any of the other fragments besides "case 0" everything works fine.

I always transition using the same code:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new AnalyzeFragment(), "Analyze")
                    .addToBackStack("Analyze").commit();
```

My fragment onCreate() all look the same:

```
    View view;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
    ActionBar actionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("Analyze");
    if(view == null)
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_analyze, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

Just to make this problem a little more confusing, every once in a while it will randomly start working perfectly even when I change absolutely nothing in my code.

Comment: Use `popBackStackImmediate()` if you want too see it immediately.

Comment: @MuratK. "fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();" is what I call in onBackPressed()

Comment: You use .Add(), I think .replace() would be a better choice here